# What happened whith software-center - authentification failed?

Tags: software-center, authentication

```
2014-05-04 16:00:34,847 - softwarecenter.backend.zeitgeist_logger - WARNING - Support for Zeitgeist disabled
2014-05-04 16:00:35,910 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2014-05-04 16:00:42,923 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Error.notAvailable: Geoclue master client has no usable Address providers'
2014-05-04 16:00:44,763 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2014-05-04 16:00:44,822 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2014-05-04 16:00:44,883 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2014-05-04 16:00:44,883 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2014-05-04 16:00:45,280 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 15.2.7, x1, 2405Mhz, 1001MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 15.2.7, x1, 2405Mhz, 1001MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:001] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:092] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:092] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:093] Cpu: 15.2.7, x1, 2405Mhz, 1001MB
[000:093] Computer model: Not available
[000:003] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:003] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:004] Cpu: 15.2.7, x1, 2405Mhz, 1001MB
[000:004] Computer model: Not available
[000:004] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:004] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:004] Using Gtk2 toolkit
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 175 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 193 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 205 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 219 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 228 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 238 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 248 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 257 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 266 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 275 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 284 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 293 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 318 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 333 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 342 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 351 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 360 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 386 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 410 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 425 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 449 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 461 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 470 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 479 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 496 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 505 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 514 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 523 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 548 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 557 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 580 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 589 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 598 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 607 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 616 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 635 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 644 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
2014-05-04 16:07:18,078 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - error creating bsddb: '(22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')' (corrupted?)
2014-05-04 16:07:18,358 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - ERROR - trying to repair DB failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 358, in _save_review_stats_cache_blocking
    self._dump_bsddbm_for_unity(outfile, outdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 377, in _dump_bsddbm_for_unity
    0600)
DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 75 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 142 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 653 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
2014-05-04 16:07:20,742 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Error.notAvailable: Geoclue master client has no usable Address providers'
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 20 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 665 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
2014-05-04 16:07:31,910 - softwarecenter.db.utils - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 686 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 697 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 706 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 715 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 724 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 739 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 748 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 757 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 766 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 802 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 813 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 822 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 831 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 843 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 852 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 861 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 870 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 879 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 889 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 902 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 934 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 943 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 952 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 961 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 977 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 999 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1008 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1017 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1026 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1039 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1049 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1058 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1071 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1080 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1089 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1098 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/viewswitcher.py", line 149, in config_view
    pane = vm.set_active_view(view_id)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/installedpane.py", line 143, in init_view
    self.oneconf_handler = get_oneconf_handler(self.oneconf_viewpickler)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/oneconfhandler/__init__.py", line 32, in get_oneconf_handler
    oneconf_handler = OneConfHandler(oneconfviewpickler)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/oneconfhandler/core.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.oneconf = DbusConnect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oneconf/dbusconnect.py", line 152, in __init__
    HOSTS_OBJECT_NAME)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/share/oneconf/oneconf-service exited with status 1
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py:404: Warning: Source ID 1110 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._timeout)
```